# Stuck in a calendar on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 3G. How can I get out of one of Calendars on my iPhone.  It is stuck in an empty calendar and doesn't allow me to get out of it to add any new events.  I've tried backing out of the calendar program to no avail.  And I've restarted my phone, also to no avail.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

- Double tap the start button, and it will bring up a list of running programs.
- Press and hold one of them, and they will start to jiggle, and show an - icon in the upper left corner.
- Find the calendar program, and tap the -.
- Rinse and repeat for any other apps you're having trouble with.  I like to periodically go through the list and close down apps I'm not using/won't use for a while

NOTE: Do this from the home screen. If you are in the app it won't appear in the queue of running apps.

Comment: My iPhone 3GS (running iOS5.01) stuck in the calendar add event. The 'Done' button would not respond. After reading the 'SplinterReality' answer, I did the double-click Start button and what showed across the foot was what I took to be a 'history' of recently opened Apps, not currently running Apps. I held down on the Calendar icon and 'minus' icons showed on all the Apps. I hit the Calendar minus sign, then wiped down the screen to bring the home screen Apps up on display, then checked out the Calendar again, and everything was back to normal. No changes were lost, thankfully. Thanks Splinter

Comment: Sorry about the original accuracy of this answer.  Hadn't actually done this in a while, but remembered that it was there.  I've corrected the answer for accuracy.  Don't forget to clear out your running apps every once in a while, especially if your iPhone is getting slow!

Comment: @Splinter Your answer is a good solution to this particular problem, an App that has somehow began misbehaving. Your last point however, about doing this from time to time to "close down apps..." and clearing out "Running" apps if your phone is "getting slow", is a bit of misinformation that has gotten really pervasive lately.  There is an excellent article by Fraser Speirs (http://goo.gl/Q2Wzs) over on Macworld that covers exactly how iOS multitasking works, and why all those apps in the multitasking drawer are not, generally speaking, "Running" Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. However, when I did the double click, it brought up all open programs EXCEPT the calendar.  I had to manually shut off and power back on, then my calendar item I added was there with the changes I had made.

Answer (score 0):

This may suck, but try syncing through iTunes and manually removing the calendar, and re-adding it in an additional sync.

For future reference, iOS5 supports manual removal of Calendars. Unfortunately, only the iPhone 3GS and above are supported on iOS5. Good luck!